# Activate paging in kernel programming

Tags: c, assembly, kernel, paging

I'm reading this tutorial "http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/6.-Paging.html" about kenrel programming and the author is using the below struct to build the page directory

```
typedef struct page_directory
{
    /**
       Array of pointers to pagetables.
    **/
    page_table_t *tables[1024];
    /**
       Array of pointers to the pagetables above, but gives their *physical*
       location, for loading into the CR3 register.
    **/
    u32int tablesPhysical[1024];

    /**
       The physical address of tablesPhysical. This comes into play
       when we get our kernel heap allocated and the directory
       may be in a different location in virtual memory.
    **/
    u32int physicalAddr;
} page_directory_t;
```

my question is why he is loading the address of the page directory like this in the **function void switch_page_directory(page_directory_t *new);**

```
 asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr3":: "r"(&dir->tablesPhysical));
```

and not like this

```
 asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr3":: "r"(current_directory ));
```

I've been testing with as shown in the code below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct page
{
   unsigned int present    : 1;   // Page present in memory
   unsigned int rw         : 1;   // Read-only if clear, readwrite if set
   unsigned int user       : 1;   // Supervisor level only if clear
   unsigned int accessed   : 1;   // Has the page been accessed since last refresh?
   unsigned int dirty      : 1;   // Has the page been written to since last refresh?
   unsigned int unused     : 7;   // Amalgamation of unused and reserved bits
   unsigned int frame      : 20;  // Frame address (shifted right 12 bits)
} page_t;

typedef struct page_table
{
   page_t pages[1024];
} page_table_t;

typedef struct page_directory
{
   page_table_t *tables[1024];
   unsigned int tablesPhysical[1024];
   unsigned int physicalAddr;
} page_directory_t;

int main()
{

page_directory_t *n;
n = malloc(sizeof(page_directory_t));
printf("n=%p i=%p y=%p\n", n,&n->tablesPhysical, &n->tables);


}
```

the result is below

```
n=0x833b008 i=0x833c008 y=0x833b008
```

I'm not sure why the address is always the same for the printf?

Comment: Well, that's exactly what the comment in your C source explains, no?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? he's using tablesPhysical and it's the second type in the struct.

Comment: Yeah, because for `%%cr3` you need physical addresses. The pointers in the first struct member are virtual addresses.

Answer (score 0):

your function is not written correctly, and you don't include the whole relevant code in the question.

That said, I'd say that the text is unclear, but I'd read the Multitasking segment, which covers what current_directory is eventually used for.